# Jenkins pipeline to deploy on Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

Im still new to jenkins and kubernetes, I want to deploy a python app on my (minikube) kubernetes cluster. For that I have my Jenkins instance running inside my minikube cluster. My jenkinsfile looks like this,(Im not sure what type of agent I need to use to perform this job.)

```
def podTemplate = """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jenkins-slave
    image: jenkinsci/slave
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - infinity
"""

pipeline {
    agent {
            kubernetes {
                yaml podTemplate
                defaultContainer 'jenkins-slave'
            }
        }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
            container('jenkins-slave') {
                script {
                    kubernetesDeploy(configs: "deployment.yaml", kubeconfigId: "myconfig")
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my pipeline always ends with this error.

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] kubernetesDeploy
Starting Kubernetes deployment
ERROR: ERROR: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeployContext.clientFactory(KubernetesDeployContext.java:284)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:58)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeploy.perform(KubernetesDeploy.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Kubernetes deployment ended with HasError
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have another pipelines to build docker images that runs fine.

Comment: Hi @Alan have you resolved this? Im facing the same issue...

Comment: @Ranic No, couldnt find the solution so I switched to ArgoCD.

Answer (score 1):

Download Kubernetes Continuous Plugin 1.0.0 version from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/kubernetes-cd/1.0.0/kubernetes-cd.hpi

To install downloaded file go to "Advanced" tab and then upload it to the "Deploy Plugin" section and then click "Deploy" button as shown below:
[image]

Then run manually:

```
docker stop <jenkins_container_ID_or_name>
docker start <jenkins_container_ID_or_name>
```

Then browse to your web browser to load the Jenkins server and click on "Build Now" of your Pipeline.
This will resolve the above issue.